# Paypal DoCapture batch process loop

Tags: loops, paypal

I am trying to implement a batch process for the doCapture API from paypal. I have the code below and it only processes the first record of the database...Help!!
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
<?php
include("xxxxx.php");<---- this is just the database connection

$query2="SELECT *
    FROM x where payment_status = 'Pending'";
//  WHERE custom IN (
    // SELECT custom
    //  FROM x
    //   GROUP BY custom
     //  HAVING count(custom) > 1
     // ) 
    //ORDER BY custom";
$results=mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results); 
$row_count=mysql_num_rows($results);
echo $row_count;
//$auth=$row2['auth_id'];
//while($row2 =mysql_fetch_array($results)){

$arrSize=sizeof($row_count);

for ($number = 0; $number < $arrSize; $number++) {

//for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++){
echo $row2['auth_id']; // prints hello


//echo $row2['auth_id'];
/** DoCapture NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Capture a payment. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
//for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++){
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('');
    $API_Password = urlencode('');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('.');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$authorizationID = urlencode($row2['auth_id']);

$amount = urlencode('1.99');
$currency = urlencode('USD');                           // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$completeCodeType = urlencode('Complete');              // or 'NotComplete'
$invoiceID = urlencode('example_invoice_id');
$note = urlencode('example_note');

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr="&AUTHORIZATIONID=$authorizationID&AMT=$amount&COMPLETETYPE=$completeCodeType&CURRENCYCODE=$currency&NOTE=$note";



// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoCapture', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('Capture Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else  {
    exit('DoCapture failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
//}
}}
//}

?>
```

Comment: Lets throw some debugging in there! Start to echo the number of rows you received, print_r some arrays to figure out where exactly the issue is at. Troubleshoot the script step by step. If you have an IDE like Netbeans or Zend, use breakpoints and look at data as it is being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only fetching one row out of the database, because your `$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results);` line is outside of your `for` loop.  Essentially, you're trying to capture the same payment over and over again, and I'm willing to bet that only the first one is succeeding.  Move the fetch statement to just inside the `for` loop.